# Jersey Java service with ASP.NET REST client

Tags: java, .net, web-services, rest, jersey-client

I have written a Java RESTful web-service using Jersey:

```
@Path("UserInfoWebService")
public class UserInfoWebService {

@GET
@Path("/name/{i}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String userInfo(@PathParam("i") String i) {
    String name = i;
    return "<User><Name>" + name + "</Name></User>" ;
}
```

I have to call this service from an application which is already written in .NET and I'm not sure if Jersey also supports the .NET framework. How can I do this task? I have already gone through various posts but I found no proper explanation.

I'm trying to create the client in ASP.NET. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can consume a REST web service from whatever technology you want, including ASP.NET.

Have a look at ASP.NET's [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138077%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and its accompanying example: [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)